# How to deal with the new version of a bug "numpy.linalg.linalg.LinAlgError" when running a python script?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, nan, hdf5

I have installed all my needed python packages under Anaconda3 on a CentOS machine. The input files, that the script depends on, are a few [GB] `.hdf5` files, in which any numerical value ( regardless of being an `infinity` or a `NaN` ) is meaningful. And a few of my `.hdf5` files do seem to have such values in some of their lines. However, `numpy` doesn't seem to respect that. I did some research and it does seem there used to be another version of such an error as a bug, about two years ago. 
(https://github.com/quantopian/zipline/issues/473)

Exact error message I am receiving is:

> File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py", line 1122, in eig
>       _assertFinite(a)
>     File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py", line 217, in _assertFinite
>       raise LinAlgError("Array must not contain infs or NaNs")
>   numpy.linalg.linalg.LinAlgError: Array must not contain infs or NaNs

After checking some packages of `Python` itself ( rather than `Anaconda3`), I noticed that some of the packages are in fact outdated; however I would like to persist on using `Anaconda3` rather than python itself.

**Is it possible to modify** some lines inside the infected package, so that I no longer receive unrecognizable *infinities* and *NaNs*?

**Is modifying the file** `/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py` a better idea than actually upgrading any package?

(If not which package needs to be upgraded?) in a way that it won't damage other capabilities of the modules.

Here are some basic info about my systems and packages:

```
uname -r
```

> 2.6.32-573.22.1.el6.x86_64

```
conda --v
```

> conda 4.2.13

```
conda list

> # packages in environment at /usr/local/anaconda3:
#
_license                  1.1                      py35_1  
_nb_ext_conf              0.3.0                    py35_0  
alabaster                 0.7.9                    py35_0  
anaconda                  4.2.0               np111py35_0  
anaconda-clean            1.0.0                    py35_0  
anaconda-client           1.5.1                    py35_0  
anaconda-navigator        1.3.1                    py35_0  
argcomplete               1.0.0                    py35_1  
astroid                   1.4.7                    py35_0  
astropy                   1.2.1               np111py35_0  
babel                     2.3.4                    py35_0  
backports                 1.0                      py35_0  
beautifulsoup4            4.5.1                    py35_0  
bitarray                  0.8.1                    py35_0  
blaze                     0.10.1                   py35_0  
bokeh                     0.12.2                   py35_0  
boto                      2.42.0                   py35_0  
Bottleneck                1.2.0                     <pip>
bottleneck                1.1.0               np111py35_0  
cairo                     1.12.18                       6  
cffi                      1.7.0                    py35_0  
chest                     0.2.3                    py35_0  
click                     6.6                      py35_0  
cloudpickle               0.2.1                    py35_0  
clyent                    1.2.2                    py35_0  
colorama                  0.3.7                    py35_0  
conda                     4.2.13                   py35_0  
conda-build               2.0.2                    py35_0  
conda-env                 2.6.0                         0  
configobj                 5.0.6                    py35_0  
contextlib2               0.5.3                    py35_0  
corner                    2.0.1                     <pip>
cryptography              1.5                      py35_0  
curl                      7.49.0                        1  
CXX                       7.0.1                     <pip>
cycler                    0.10.0                   py35_0  
cython                    0.24.1                   py35_0  
cytoolz                   0.8.0                    py35_0  
dask                      0.11.0                   py35_0  
datashape                 0.5.2                    py35_0  
dbus                      1.10.10                       0  
decorator                 4.0.10                   py35_0  
dill                      0.2.5                    py35_0  
distribute                0.7.3                     <pip>
docutils                  0.12                     py35_2  
dynd-python               0.7.2                    py35_0  
emcee                     2.2.1                     <pip>
entrypoints               0.2.2                    py35_0  
et_xmlfile                1.0.1                    py35_0  
expat                     2.1.0                         0  
fastcache                 1.0.2                    py35_1  
filelock                  2.0.6                    py35_0  
flask                     0.11.1                   py35_0  
flask-cors                2.1.2                    py35_0  
fontconfig                2.11.1                        6  
freetype                  2.5.5                         1  
get_terminal_size         1.0.0                    py35_0  
gevent                    1.1.2                    py35_0  
glib                      2.43.0                        1  
greenlet                  0.4.10                   py35_0  
gst-plugins-base          1.8.0                         0  
gstreamer                 1.8.0                         0  
h5py                      2.6.0               np111py35_2  
harfbuzz                  0.9.39                        1  
hdf5                      1.8.17                        1  
heapdict                  1.0.0                    py35_1  
icu                       54.1                          0  
idna                      2.1                      py35_0  
imagesize                 0.7.1                    py35_0  
ipykernel                 4.5.0                    py35_0  
ipython                   5.1.0                    py35_0  
ipython_genutils          0.1.0                    py35_0  
ipywidgets                5.2.2                    py35_0  
itsdangerous              0.24                     py35_0  
jbig                      2.1                           0  
jdcal                     1.2                      py35_1  
jedi                      0.9.0                    py35_1  
jinja2                    2.8                      py35_1  
jpeg                      8d                            2  
jsonschema                2.5.1                    py35_0  
jupyter                   1.0.0                    py35_3  
jupyter_client            4.4.0                    py35_0  
jupyter_console           5.0.0                    py35_0  
jupyter_core              4.2.0                    py35_0  
lazy-object-proxy         1.2.1                    py35_0  
libdynd                   0.7.2                         0  
libffi                    3.2.1                         0  
libgcc                    4.8.5                         2  
libgfortran               3.0.0                         1  
libpng                    1.6.22                        0  
libsodium                 1.0.10                        0  
libtiff                   4.0.6                         2  
libxcb                    1.12                          1  
libxml2                   2.9.2                         0  
libxslt                   1.1.28                        0  
llvmlite                  0.13.0                   py35_0  
locket                    0.2.0                    py35_1  
lxml                      3.6.4                    py35_0  
markupsafe                0.23                     py35_2  
matplotlib                1.5.3               np111py35_1  
mistune                   0.7.3                    py35_0  
mkl                       11.3.3                        0  
mkl-service               1.1.2                    py35_2  
mpmath                    0.19                     py35_1  
multipledispatch          0.4.8                    py35_0  
nb_anacondacloud          1.2.0                    py35_0  
nb_conda                  2.0.0                    py35_0  
nb_conda_kernels          2.0.0                    py35_0  
nbconvert                 4.2.0                    py35_0  
nbformat                  4.1.0                    py35_0  
nbpresent                 3.0.2                    py35_0  
networkx                  1.11                     py35_0  
nltk                      3.2.1                    py35_0  
nose                      1.3.7                    py35_1  
notebook                  4.2.3                    py35_0  
numba                     0.28.1              np111py35_0  
numexpr                   2.6.1               np111py35_0  
numpy                     1.11.2                    <pip>
numpy                     1.12.0b1                  <pip>
numpy                     1.11.2                   py35_0  
odo                       0.5.0                    py35_1  
openpyxl                  2.3.2                    py35_0  
openssl                   1.0.2j                        0  
pandas                    0.19.1              np111py35_0  
partd                     0.3.6                    py35_0  
patchelf                  0.9                           0  
path.py                   8.2.1                    py35_0  
path.py                   8.2.1                     <pip>
pathlib2                  2.1.0                    py35_0  
patsy                     0.4.1                    py35_0  
pep8                      1.7.0                    py35_0  
pexpect                   4.0.1                    py35_0  
pickleshare               0.7.4                    py35_0  
pillow                    3.3.1                    py35_0  
pip                       9.0.1                    py35_0  
pixman                    0.32.6                        0  
pkginfo                   1.3.2                    py35_0  
ply                       3.9                      py35_0  
prompt_toolkit            1.0.3                    py35_0  
psutil                    4.3.1                    py35_0  
ptyprocess                0.5.1                    py35_0  
py                        1.4.31                   py35_0  
pyasn1                    0.1.9                    py35_0  
pycosat                   0.6.1                    py35_1  
pycparser                 2.14                     py35_1  
pycrypto                  2.6.1                    py35_4  
pycurl                    7.43.0                   py35_0  
pyflakes                  1.3.0                    py35_0  
pygments                  2.1.3                    py35_0  
pylint                    1.5.4                    py35_1  
pyopenssl                 16.0.0                   py35_0  
pyparsing                 2.1.4                    py35_0  
pyqt                      5.6.0                    py35_0  
PyQt-Fit                  1.3.4                     <pip>
pytables                  3.2.3.1             np111py35_0  
pytest                    2.9.2                    py35_0  
python                    3.5.2                         0  
python-dateutil           2.5.3                    py35_0  
pytz                      2016.6.1                 py35_0  
pyyaml                    3.12                     py35_0  
pyzmq                     15.4.0                   py35_0  
qt                        5.6.0                         1  
QtPy                      1.1.2                     <pip>
readline                  6.2                           2  
redis                     3.2.0                         0  
redis-py                  2.10.5                   py35_0  
requests                  2.11.1                   py35_0  
rope                      0.9.4                    py35_1  
ruamel_yaml               0.11.14                  py35_0  
scikit-image              0.12.3              np111py35_1  
scikit-learn              0.17.1              np111py35_2  
scipy                     0.18.1              np111py35_0  
setuptools                27.2.0                   py35_0  
simplegeneric             0.8.1                    py35_1  
singledispatch            3.4.0.3                  py35_0  
sip                       4.18                     py35_0  
six                       1.10.0                   py35_0  
snowballstemmer           1.2.1                    py35_0  
sockjs-tornado            1.0.3                    py35_0  
sphinx                    1.4.6                    py35_0  
spyder                    3.0.0                    py35_0  
sqlalchemy                1.0.13                   py35_0  
sqlite                    3.13.0                        0  
statsmodels               0.6.1               np111py35_1  
svgutils                  0.2.0                     <pip>
sympy                     1.0                      py35_0  
terminado                 0.6                      py35_0  
tk                        8.5.18                        0  
toolz                     0.8.0                    py35_0  
tornado                   4.4.1                    py35_0  
traitlets                 4.3.0                    py35_0  
uncertainties             3.0.1                     <pip>
unicodecsv                0.14.1                   py35_0  
wcwidth                   0.1.7                    py35_0  
werkzeug                  0.11.11                  py35_0  
wheel                     0.29.0                   py35_0  
widgetsnbextension        1.2.6                    py35_0  
wrapt                     1.10.6                   py35_0  
xlrd                      1.0.0                    py35_0  
xlsxwriter                0.9.3                    py35_0  
xlwt                      1.1.2                    py35_0  
xz                        5.2.2                         0  
yaml                      0.1.6                         0  
zeromq                    4.1.4                         0  
zlib                      1.2.8                         3
```

I have learnt that in `numpy` there is a method called **`.nan_to_num()`**, where one can convert any of **`{ np.nan | np.inf | -np.inf }`** into some appropriate number, according to the following webpage (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nan_to_num.html).

However the **`hdf5`** files are very huge ( ~3 GB ) and I don't know if this is the only way around to fix the issue.

Comment: Welcome, **it is not a bug, it is an intention.** As both the `np.nan`-s and `np.inf`-s are principally necessary values in a serious numerical package like `numpy` out of question is, the problem is rather in situations, that other packages ( not your case ) and/or some methods ( in `numpy.linalg.linalg` ) simply **cannot process** ( the former ) or **must not receive** such values ( the latter ). This is called a DataSanity care-taking. Yes, HDF5 files may be large, may be big or might be even HUGE, but it is the DataEngineering task to provide proper DataSanitisation efforts, to meet a def.